# how to prove that a set is not dense?

Tags: infinity, density-function

> Let $A$ be a set of real numbers such that ⊆(1,∞) and dense in $(1,\infty)$, I would like to prove that $B= \left\{\frac{a}{(a+1)n^2}|a∈A,n∈N\right\}$ is not dense in $[1,0]$.

Well I'm having some trouble showing it after I said let $x,y\in[0,1]$ while $y>x$ that for every $b\in B$ we get $b\geq y$ or $b\leq x$ and then I get stuck in showing that it leads to $A$ and therefore $B$ is not dense in $[0,1]$.

Comment: If $0.25<\frac{a}{(a+1)n^2}<0.5 $, then $\frac{n^2}{4}<\frac{a}{a+1}<\frac{n^2}{2}$ So n=1, so $\frac{a}{a+1}<\frac{1}{2}$ and this is a contradict

Comment: yes but for specific n it will not be proved although it's true. I need to show it for every n and for x,y not specifically but in general. Does someone have an idea?